# PCIDSS with Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, pci-dss

Wondering if anyone can shed any light on if using google tag manager is compliant with PCIDSS?

I know there are provisions in it to ensure tags cannot be injected, such as securing servers, xss protections etc, but can't find anything on if a tag manager which enables dynamic html changes is ok or not.

I can see both arguments...

Comment: This is an interesting question...but I don't know the answer.